# How to use Druid with Ambari?

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, druid

I am very new to [Druid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Druid_(open-source_data_store)), a column-oriented, open-source, distributed data store written in Java.

I need to start multiple services (nodes) in order to work smoothly Druid. Is there a good way to auto start the services?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP)/distribution that will install Zookeeper/HDFS/[Druid](https://hortonworks.com/open-source/druid/)/Postgresql/Hadoop and you are good to go.
There is also [a video guide](https://youtu.be/pvtdvoZ83uk) available on how to install Druid step-by-step.

Otherwise you can do it your self by building Druid from source and copy jars and configs around.

Answer (score 0):

You can find patch for Ambari Druid integration, [AMBARI-17981](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-17981), and which will be included as of Ambari v2.5.

Patch file contains all that information in the form of a diff file. 
Typically you need to checkout the source code, apply the patch, and then build the project.